# Passing information in a dynamic link

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable in a php link, however, i can not seem to get it to work, below is my code, i have tried writing it several ways, but no matter what i try it doesn't seem to matter.

```
  echo "<href='ownpage.php?page='.&pageNum + 1.'>Click </a>";
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is it the code you tried in several ways?? Because I could not find the start tag of hyperlink in your code...

echo "<a href='ownpage.php?page='.($pageNum + 1).'>Click </a>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
echo "<a href='ownpage.php?page=".($pageNum + 1)."'>Click </a>";
```

Comment: Thanks, but again it doesn't show on the page, there is no click link

Comment: @StanWilliams, if my answer helped you don't forget to accept so that SO contributors know that your question has been answered. And if you feel like you can upvote my answer as well :D